# How do I get a value from a Textbox, put it in a string, and when i click 2 buttons, it shows (kinda like a global?) C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to take the value from the TextBox to a string, then use it as a string on a button click. I do not want to have it inside my Button click since i have to use it on other buttons as well.
Something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string ab = textBox1.Text;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ab);
    }       

}
```

EDIT 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string ab = textBox1.Text;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ab);
        }     
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ab+" Hello");
        }
```

Comment: you need same button click event to use with multiple buttons ?

Comment: Have you tried making `ab` property or making a method to return the text?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A private method can be used to achieve this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Will return string on textBox1 uppon calling
     private string ab(){
       return textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ab());
    }     
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ab()+" Hello");
    }
}
```